# SRAM Force 22 chainset in an otherwise 10-speed SRAM setup

Tags: derailleur, crankset, sram, front, compact-crankset

I notice that SRAM web site still lists "regular" 10-speed Force chainset as one of their products. However, my attempts to find it for sale online came up with almost nothing. It seems to be "barely" available at some places, but the chainring/BB/crank length combination I'm interested in (50/34, GXP, 172.5mm) proves to be impossible to find.

Hence the question: what about SRAM Force22 chainsets? Will they work in a 10-speed setup? Specifically, with regular SRAM Force front derailleur and shifter?

Comment: http://velonews.competitor.com/2012/03/news/it-works-we-test-sram-red-backwards-compatibility_209270

Comment: Are you riding a 10speed cassette/freehub/chain already and are now looking for the crank?

Comment: @ebrohman: Yes, precisely. Actually I have been using SRAM Rival cranks. And my drive-side crank just went out of commision becuse of a seized pedal. I thought about upgrading to Force, but apparently I'll just get another Rival. These still seem to be available in 10-speed flavor.

Answer (score 2):

If you are prepared to move down to the SRAM Apex model, you can still get a 50/34 172.5mm version http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/au/en/sram-apex-white-gxp-compact-10sp-chainset/rp-prod83674

The first question and answer here indicates that an 11 spped chainring will work with a 10 speed chain: http://velonews.competitor.com/2015/03/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-10-11-speed-drivetrain-component-compatibility_362722

Comment: The first question at the link seems to be about: a) using 10-speed chainset on an 11-speed bicycle, b) using 10-speed cranks(spider)  with 11-speed chainrings on an 11-speed bicycle. I.e. it is all about 11-speed bicycles. My question is about 10-speed bicycle. The answer does mention though that 11-speed chainsets work on 10-speed bicycles.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use a Force 22.  I have a Force 22 GXP and a RED 22 BB30 crank.  I've run both successfully on different bikes - one with a Mavic 11 speed free-hub, running a 10 speed cassette with a spacer, the other with a regular 10 speed free-hub and cassette.

I usually do this in the winter to run a 10 speed tubular wheel & knobby tire combo at low pressure on my 11 speed.

What you don't get with the 'regular' non '22' Force front derailleur is the *yaw* technology that helps with chain rub. But, it will still work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use a 22 chain ring on an otherwise 10 speed SRAM drivetrain.

At our shop, we have used the front crank interchangeably for months on end on multiple bikes.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed a FORCE 22 50/34 crankset on my old SRAM Force 10 spd equipped bike. Used to have SRAM Rival Crankset. I can not see any indications on why this would not work. I'm a mechanical engineer as a profession as well..

SRAM says the PC1051 chain is not compatible with Force22 chainrings, but it works fine so far. I think SRAM in this case tries to make you upgrade to 11 spd all over. Not necessary, but clearly a PC1170 chain vill not work so good with my 10 SPD cassette.